# Is there an alternative to neighbors in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am coverting my app over to cakephp 3.0 and I am having trouble finding an alternative to using neighbors in the find method.

I need to find the next record in the associated table and neighbors was a great way to do it.

```
//Open courses
$options = [
    'conditions' => ['Employees.user_id' => 1, 'CoursesEmployees.completed' => false],
    'limit' => 3,
    'contain' => 'Employees'
];
$recentOpen = $this->CoursesEmployees->find('all', $options)->toArray();

// get next module for each open course
foreach ($recentOpen as $key => &$value) {
    $currentModule = $value['CourseModule']['id'];
    $neighbors = $this->CoursesEmployees->CourseModules->find(
        'neighbors',
        ['field' => 'id', 'value' => $currentModule]
    );
    $value['CourseModule']['next_module'] = $neighbors['next']['CourseModule']['name'];
};
```

Another issue with the code I discovered is that `$this->CoursesEmployees->find('all', $options)->toArray();` seems to return a complex array with everything cakephp uses to query the table and not the actual results like I got with cakephp 2. I added the `->toArray()` as recommended with 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5518)
there is no neighbors find method in cakephp 3.

But if you follow the flow of the issue you will find a custom finder to accomplish it, maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will look to build my own finder method. At least it I know there is not replacement for it. Shame it was useful, can't see a reason to drop it. Would you have an idea when I am not getting results from the `$this->CoursesEmployees->find('all', $options)->toArray();` Cakephp 3 does not seem to do the query at this stage so there are no results, not like 2.0

Comment: I am not sure about that last problem @KeithPower . Indeed I had some situations with the same problem but I surrounded it. Maybe you can try another way of do it? like


`$query = $articles->find()->contain([
    'Authors.Addresses',
    'Comments.Authors'
]);`

Answer (score 6):

Because I loathe "Answers" that simply point to a URL where you may or may not be able to decipher a half answer today, but could be gone tomorrow, here is my replacement custom finder:

```
// In src/Models/Table/ExampleTable.php
/**
 * Find neighbors method
 */
public function findNeighbors(Query $query, array $options) {
    $id = $options['id'];
    $previous = $this->find()
            ->select('id')
            ->order(['id' => 'DESC'])
            ->where(['id <' => $id])
            ->first();
    $next = $this->find()
            ->select('id')
            ->order(['id' => 'ASC'])
            ->where(['id >' => $id])
            ->first();
    return ['prev' => $previous['id'], 'next' => $next['id']];
}
```

Called simply in the Controller:

```
// In src/Controller/ExamplesController.php
public function view($id = null) {
    ...
    $neighbors = $this->Examples->find('neighbors', ['id' => $id]);
    ....
}
```